# Pip package version conflicts despite seemingly matching ranges

Tags: python, pip

When using `pip install -r requirements.txt`, I get `ERROR: Cannot install -r requirements.txt (line 3), [...] because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.`.
And further:

```
The conflict is caused by:
    tensorflow 2.11.0 depends on protobuf<3.20 and >=3.9.2
    tensorboard 2.11.0 depends on protobuf<4 and >=3.9.2
    wandb 0.13.5 depends on protobuf!=4.0.*, !=4.21.0, <5 and >=3.12.0
```

I don't see any conflicts in these ranges - every version in `[3.12.0, 3.20)` should be fine. Can someone explain the problem?

**Update:** As a workaround, I removed all version restrictions and only specified the names of the libraries in the `requirements.txt` file. Now it works. But I still don't see a problem with the above ranges, so I'll leave the question open.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: using Python 3.9 on Windows installed in a conda environment, `pip install tensorflow==2.11.0 tensorboard==2.11.0 wandb==0.13.5` installed `protobuf==3.19.6` for me.

Comment: Please provide your complete environment specification, and the full text of the `requirements.txt` file that generates this error.

Comment: (I agree, the error message you show does not make sense, but we need to be able to reproduce it if we are to attempt to explain it.)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that, rather than using a range of versions, use a specific version you know works. That way, there won't be any problems.

I think that one of the versions of the dependencies is incompatible with the main module, and since it is within the range of versions you ask for, pip tries to intall it and fails to do so since it is incompatible.

Also, pip normally handles dependencies automatically.

Comment: I did use specific versions for each library in the `requirements.txt`. The ranges are based on the requirements of these libraries. I don't completely understand your 2nd point, but the error message I get is still not reasonable, right?